# Can't export signing identity from Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate

I go to Xcode preferences, Accounts. Select my developer account and select "Export Accounts" from the gear at the bottom of the dialog. I'm presented with a dialog, I select the location, give it a file name, enter a password in both fields and click OK. I get this error message:
"The specified item already exists in the keychain."

What's that all about and how do I export my signing identity?

Comment: hi! same here. Any solution??